# Using OnClick Listener in Listview

Tags: android

I want to be notified when an item in a listview has been clicked , I have a main activity that has a ListView , I want to be notified when an Item in a this list has been Clicked , I did not override main activity to ListActivity .

Comment: What do you have so far? Have you seen http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

               //Do all the stuffs

}  });
```

The position will inform about the item cliked on list.

Answer (score 0):

you may need extend `ListActivity` then you can override the `onListItemClick` function.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    doStuff();

    }
```